# Time-based workflow fires when

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

If I have a time-based workflow to fire on a certain date, determined by a date field, when does the field update happen? Is it at midnight on that day?

Please provide a reference if possible.

Comment: What do you mean with field update? Update caused by workflow or formula field?

Comment: The workflow rule triggers a field update to happen on a date. When does that happen?

Comment: Have you tried to test it?

Comment: No I haven't tried to test it

Answer (score 0):

To setup a Workflow Rule that triggers actions to occur at a specific time such as at the end of the business day use the process below:

1. Create a Date field on the object that the Workflow will be associated to. Be sure to give this field a descriptive label as we will be referring to it in later steps. This field does not need to be available on any Page Layouts.
2. Setup your Workflow Rule with criteria as normal. As we will be creating Time-Dependent Workflow Actions you may NOT select "Every time a record is created or edited" within the Evaluation Criteria section.
3. In addition to any other Workflow Actions create the following two actions:

   - Immediate Workflow Action: Field Update the Date field setup above in step 1 with the value TODAY().
   - Time-Dependent Workflow Action: Set your action to occur N Hours After the Date field setup in step 1 above, where N is the number of hours between midnight within your org's Default Time Zone and the time you wish for the action to take place.
4. You can find your organization's Default Time Zone at the following location: Setup | Company Profile | Company Information.

Example 1: If you would like for an e-mail to be sent out at 5:00pm EDT, and your organization's Default Time Zone is set to Eastern Daylight Time then X would be 17 hours after the Date field)

Example 2: If you would like for an e-mail to be sent out at 5:00pm EDT, and your organization's Default Time Zone is set to Pacific Daylight Time then X would be 9 hours after the Date field)

When complete Activate your Workflow Rule and verify that it functions as expected by reviewing the Time-Based Workflow queue: Setup | Monitoring | Time-Based Workflow.

Source: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004643